# "Failed to load config" error when trying to run a React project using Vite.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, yarnpkg

I'm helping a friend with a coding problem. The project they are working on uses React, as well as Vite.js. The project uses yarn for package management. The project is being run locally on a Windows 10 OS, and has been tried to be solved in Git Bash and Powershell. When running the command `yarn dev`, the following error is displayed:

```
failed to load config from C:\Users\[user-name]\OneDrive\Documents\workspace\[project%20name]\Adm\ui\vite.config.ts
error when starting dev server:
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\[user-name]\OneDrive\Documents\workspace\[project name]\Adm\ui\node_modules\vite\package.json'
    at Object.openSync (node:fs:585:3)
    at Object.readFileSync (node:fs:453:35)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Object._require.extensions.<computed> [as .js] (file:///C:/Users/[user-name]/OneDrive/Documents/workspace/[project%2520name]/Adm/ui/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-5e7f419b.js:62106:17)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

The `vite.config.ts` file is below:

```
/// <reference types="vitest" />
/// <reference types="vite/client" />

import { resolve as pathResolve } from "path";

import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import svgr from "vite-plugin-svgr";

const resolve = (path: string) => pathResolve(__dirname, path);

export default defineConfig({
  server: {
    port: [port-number],
  },
  preview: {
    port: [port-number],
  },
  plugins: [svgr(), react()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "~": resolve("src"),
    },
  },
  assetsInclude: ["src/assets"],
});
```

**What I've tried**:

- Updating yarn, node, npm
- Deleting and re-cloning the project
- Running `yarn install` before running `yarn dev`
- Switching the node version from `18.16.0` to `16.11.1` using NVM (I read somewhere that this would help as this might be a bug)

I can't seem to figure out what the issue is. Any ideas on what else I can try in terms of troubleshooting?